# java 8 stream a nested list to find a value is present

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

---

I need to find out if there is any value present for the characteristsic object . right now i am iterating all the loops to get check if value is present or not . the code is also not null safe .

```
boolean flag;
    for (ServiceGroup serviceGroup : serviceGroups) {

        List<Service> services = serviceGroup.getServices();
        for (Service service : services) {
            List<Subscription> subscriptions = service.getSubscriptions();
            for (Subscription subscription : subscriptions) {
                List<ComOrderCFS> prss = subscription.getPrss();
                for (ComOrderCFS prs : prss) {
                    List<ComCFSCharacteristsics> characteristsics = prs.getCharacteristics();
                    for (ComCFSCharacteristsics characteristsic : characteristsics) {

                        if ("SerialNumber".equals(characteristsic.getName()) && characteristsic.getValue() != null) {
                            flag = true;
                        } else {
                            flag = false;
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I tried my hand in streams but not getting the desired o/p

```
          List<ComOrderCFS> prss= serviceGroups.stream().map(ServiceGroup::getServices).flatMap(Collection::stream).map
          (Service::getSubscriptions).flatMap(Collection::stream).map(Subscription::getPrss).
          findFirst().get();
```

is there anyway to to it in java 8 and return a boolean  if present .
will appreciate a lot if the solution has comments (new to java 8)
thanks

Comment: The flag will always be set one way or the other after `if ("SerialNumber".equals(characteristsic.getName()) && characteristsic.getValue() != null) {
                            flag = true;
                        } else {
                            flag = false;
                        }` meaning: the last "characteristic" decides what value comes out. Is this really what you want?

Comment: just use [.anyMatch(item -> YOUR_CONDITION_ON_THE item))]

Answer (score 2):

```
return serviceGroups.stream()
    .map(ServiceGroup::getServices)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(Service::getSubscriptions)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(Subscription::getPrss)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(ComOrderCFS::getCharacteristics)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .anyMatch(characteristsic -> "SerialNumber".equals(characteristsic.getName()) && characteristsic.getValue() != null);
```

Edit: I assumed you don't want to overwrite `flag` on every iteration but rather want to verify if *any one* entry in that list fulfills the condition.

Comment: thanks . can you please tell me how can I  avoid nullpointer exception but adding null check in this code

Comment: Depends on what can be null.

Comment: @SachinPrakash agnostic of which attribute and applicable to all that could possibly be `null`, you can do that by ensuring to `filter` only nonnull values in the pipeline. It would look like `....filter(Objects::nonNull)...`